# Javascript data store solution using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, database, cordova

Does anyone have any experience of storing data in JavaScript across all mobile platforms using PhoneGap? My ideal solution would be to use something like SQLite, but unfortunately SQLite isn't supported across all the platforms PhoneGap supports.

I tried to ask this question a little while ago, but it got quite a few negative marks. If you think this is a bad / pointless question I would love to know as it will hopefully help me to understand the problem!

Cheers,
Nick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would check out [Lawnchair](http://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair). It has a simple storage API (using SQLite, domStorage or Gears behind the scenes) for iPhone, Android and PalmOS as well as any other browser that supports cookies.

Comment: Genius - thankyou Dave. I'll check this out today. It sounds like it could be just the ticket!

Comment: After some investigation, this looks like it should do the job. Thanks for your help.